# Decompiling code from APK changed code

Tags: android, apk, decompiler

I recently had to uninstall Android Studio from my computer and it erased all of my project files, luckily I still had an APK from the recent version and was able to decompile the code correctly. All of my files are there and I have been able to see the java class code through note pad but it looks like some things were changed in the code. Will they change back when I import the project back into the Android Studio? Here is an example of my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity
  extends AppCompatActivity
{
  private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
  private static final String hasUserRatedAppKey = "hasUserRatedApp";
  private static final String settingsKey = "MyAppSettings";
  private String SENDER_ID = "993190397898";
  private CustomAdapter adapter;
  Fragment fragment;
  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private ListView mDrawerList;
  private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
  private CharSequence mTitle;
  String[] menutitles;
  private List<RowItem> rowItems;

  private void selectItem(int paramInt)
  {
    switch (paramInt)
    {
    }
    for (;;)
    {
      this.mDrawerList.setItemChecked(paramInt, true);
      setTitle("Converjz");
      this.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(this.mDrawerList);
      return;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
      finish();
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, Time.class));
      finish();
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, Temperature.class));
      finish();
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, Weight.class));
      finish();
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, Length.class));
      finish();
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, Money.class));
      finish();
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, Metric.class));
      finish();
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, Food.class));
      finish();
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, Data.class));
      finish();
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, Frequency.class));
      finish();
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, Numeral.class));
      finish();
    }
  }

  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration paramConfiguration)
  {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(paramConfiguration);
    this.mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(paramConfiguration);
  }

  protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(2130968609);
    paramBundle = ((AnalyticsTracker)getApplication()).getTracker(AnalyticsTracker.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    paramBundle.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
    paramBundle.setScreenName("Home");
    paramBundle.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
    this.menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(2131558424);
    this.mDrawerLayout = ((DrawerLayout)findViewById(2131689566));
    this.mDrawerList = ((ListView)findViewById(2131689573));
    this.mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, 2130968608, 2131689522, this.menutitles));
    paramBundle = getTitle();
    this.mDrawerTitle = paramBundle;
    this.mTitle = paramBundle;
    this.mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener(null));
    this.mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, this.mDrawerLayout, 2131230781, 2131230780)
    {
      public void onDrawerClosed(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        super.onDrawerClosed(paramAnonymousView);
        MainActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(MainActivity.this.mTitle);
        MainActivity.this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
      }

      public void onDrawerOpened(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        super.onDrawerOpened(paramAnonymousView);
        MainActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(MainActivity.this.mDrawerTitle);
        MainActivity.this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
      }
    };
    this.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this.mDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getResources().getConfiguration();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(16908290, new adView());
    ((AdView)findViewById(2131689565)).loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    paramBundle = (Button)findViewById(2131689593);
    final ObjectAnimator localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((RelativeLayout)findViewById(2131689592), new PropertyValuesHolder[] { PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", new float[] { 1.2F }), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", new float[] { 1.2F }) });
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatCount(-1);
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatMode(2);
    paramBundle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        localObjectAnimator.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Metric.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
          }
        }, 500L);
      }
    });
    paramBundle = (Button)findViewById(2131689580);
    localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((RelativeLayout)findViewById(2131689579), new PropertyValuesHolder[] { PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", new float[] { 1.2F }), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", new float[] { 1.2F }) });
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatCount(-1);
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatMode(2);
    paramBundle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        localObjectAnimator.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Time.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
          }
        }, 500L);
      }
    });
    paramBundle = (Button)findViewById(2131689583);
    localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((RelativeLayout)findViewById(2131689581), new PropertyValuesHolder[] { PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", new float[] { 1.2F }), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", new float[] { 1.2F }) });
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatCount(-1);
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatMode(2);
    paramBundle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        localObjectAnimator.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Temperature.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
          }
        }, 500L);
      }
    });
    paramBundle = (Button)findViewById(2131689585);
    localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((RelativeLayout)findViewById(2131689584), new PropertyValuesHolder[] { PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", new float[] { 1.2F }), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", new float[] { 1.2F }) });
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatCount(-1);
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatMode(2);
    paramBundle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        localObjectAnimator.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Weight.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
          }
        }, 500L);
      }
    });
    paramBundle = (Button)findViewById(2131689589);
    localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((RelativeLayout)findViewById(2131689586), new PropertyValuesHolder[] { PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", new float[] { 1.2F }), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", new float[] { 1.2F }) });
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatCount(-1);
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatMode(2);
    paramBundle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        localObjectAnimator.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Length.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
          }
        }, 500L);
      }
    });
    paramBundle = (Button)findViewById(2131689591);
    localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((RelativeLayout)findViewById(2131689574), new PropertyValuesHolder[] { PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", new float[] { 1.2F }), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", new float[] { 1.2F }) });
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatCount(-1);
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatMode(2);
    paramBundle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        localObjectAnimator.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Money.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
          }
        }, 500L);
      }
    });
    paramBundle = (Button)findViewById(2131689597);
    localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((RelativeLayout)findViewById(2131689596), new PropertyValuesHolder[] { PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", new float[] { 1.2F }), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", new float[] { 1.2F }) });
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatCount(-1);
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatMode(2);
    paramBundle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        localObjectAnimator.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Food.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
          }
        }, 500L);
      }
    });
    paramBundle = (Button)findViewById(2131689599);
    localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((RelativeLayout)findViewById(2131689598), new PropertyValuesHolder[] { PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", new float[] { 1.2F }), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", new float[] { 1.2F }) });
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatCount(-1);
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatMode(2);
    paramBundle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        localObjectAnimator.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Data.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
          }
        }, 500L);
      }
    });
    paramBundle = (Button)findViewById(2131689602);
    localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((RelativeLayout)findViewById(2131689600), new PropertyValuesHolder[] { PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", new float[] { 1.2F }), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", new float[] { 1.2F }) });
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatCount(-1);
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatMode(2);
    paramBundle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        localObjectAnimator.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Frequency.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
          }
        }, 500L);
      }
    });
    paramBundle = (Button)findViewById(2131689605);
    localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((RelativeLayout)findViewById(2131689604), new PropertyValuesHolder[] { PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", new float[] { 1.2F }), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", new float[] { 1.2F }) });
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatCount(-1);
    localObjectAnimator.setRepeatMode(2);
    paramBundle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        localObjectAnimator.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Numeral.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
          }
        }, 500L);
      }
    });
  }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu)
  {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(2131755008, paramMenu);
    return true;
  }

  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem paramMenuItem)
  {
    if (this.mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(paramMenuItem)) {
      return true;
    }
    switch (paramMenuItem.getItemId())
    {
    }
    for (;;)
    {
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(paramMenuItem);
      startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
      continue;
      Object localObject = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TechnologyForTomorrow.Converjz"));
      try
      {
        startActivity((Intent)localObject);
        localObject = ((AnalyticsTracker)getApplication()).getTracker(AnalyticsTracker.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        ((Tracker)localObject).enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        ((Tracker)localObject).setScreenName("EULA");
        ((Tracker)localObject).send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
      }
      catch (ActivityNotFoundException localActivityNotFoundException) {}
      continue;
      startActivity(new Intent(this, EULA.class));
    }
  }

  protected void onPostCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onPostCreate(paramBundle);
    this.mDrawerToggle.syncState();
  }

  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu)
  {
    this.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(this.mDrawerList);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(paramMenu);
  }

  public void setTitle(CharSequence paramCharSequence)
  {
    this.mTitle = paramCharSequence;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(this.mTitle);
  }

  private class DrawerItemClickListener
    implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
  {
    private DrawerItemClickListener() {}

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt, long paramLong)
    {
      MainActivity.this.selectItem(paramInt);
    }
  }
}


/* Location:              C:\Noah's stuff\dex2jar-2.0\Converjz-dex2jar.jar!\course\labs\converjz\MainActivity.class
 * Java compiler version: 6 (50.0)
 * JD-Core Version:       0.7.1
 */
```

Comment: Try it and let us know the result!

Comment: I will hopefully it works once android studio finishes installing. I just wanted to know if anyone had to go through the same process as me and it worked for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will they change back when I import the project back into the Android Studio?

No, because there is no "back". Android Studio has no idea that this is not the code that you want.

This is why, rather than decompiling an APK, you should have restored your project from a backup of your computer or from your version control system.

You are certainly welcome to find some other decompiler and see if it gives you results more to your liking. I would recommend that you do that after setting up a nightly backup regimen for your computer.

Comment: Well here's the thing, I was not able to do either before hand so I hope that things can possibly be fixed, apparently it worked for other people so it could possibly work for me

Comment: Get this, it worked, android was able to put the code it changes on compilation back to its original state. I am very grateful that everything is back to normal.